# Android NDK: build my static library

Tags: android-ndk

I have these files in jni folder:

- Android.mk
- Application.mk
- m_lanczos.c
- m_lanczos.h
- sresolution.cpp

and I just want to use my library in resolution.cpp like:

```
#include"m_lanczos.h"
```

What else do I have to add in Android.mk? Thank you!

```
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := super
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sresolution.cpp 
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that could be wrong:

1. You have forgot to compile m_lanczos.c:
   Then your Android.mk should look like this:

   ```
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)  
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)  

   LOCAL_MODULE := super  
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sresolution.cpp m_lanczos.c  
   LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl  

   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
   ```
2. m_lanczos is a STATIC_LIBRARY:
   Then you have to build it and include it:

   ```
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) 

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)       
   LOCAL_MODULE := m_lanczos
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := m_lanczos.c  
   LOCAL_LDLIBS +=           #needed librarys for m_lanczos, probably nothing       
   include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY) 

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)         
   LOCAL_MODULE := super  
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sresolution.cpp
   LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl  
   LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := m_lanczos
   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
   ```

But i think it will be the first one, 
i hope that i helped :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think it should be the first one! But it doesn't work for me! I didn't mention that I also use the OpenCV library and maybe it's something about that! Anyway, I write all the code in m_lanczos.h and it works!